# rename android textview

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, rename

How can I rename android text view dynamically? I want to assign a name depending on what edit text answer is given the name has to relate to a already created textview.
For instance name a is already assigned a res id in the xml
example 
       final TextView name a = 
            (TextView)  this.findViewById(R.id.Texti5);

```
    editext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) { 
            if("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(anstext.getText().toString())) {
                 // Here i want to give textview1 the 'name a'
                }}
            else
            if("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
                // Here i want to give textview1 the 'name b'
            }

        if("test5".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
            // Here i want to give textview1 the 'name c'
        }

        if("test7".equalsIgnoreCase(editext.getText().toString())) {
            // Here i want to give textview1 the 'name d'
        }
        if (editext.getText().toString() != null){
          testwrong.seText("wrong");               }
        }
      // here i want to see what name is given and give the name to textview1 so i can 
         perform click on that textview as it is clickable
      textview1.performClck();
    return true;




    } });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a method that might achieve a similar goal is to give the textview a tag depending on your if statements.

```
textview1.setTag("a");
```

Then you can get the tag back like:

```
if (textview1.getTag() == "a") {
// do something
}
```

this would, at the very least, be more conventional than what you are proposing.